# How to fix Composition Exception in Shellbootstrapper?

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

I am trying to deploy a new software application and I am getting an exception in startup that I am not getting in debug mode in my office.  The application does not start but works fine on my PC.

I tried grabbing any inner exception message but none exists.  I am unable to determine what the illegal character is or where it came from.

I am using the Caliburn.Micro framework, which I love and have not had this type of issue before.

This application is running on a machine control PC running Windows Embedded (an XP version - I am running Win7) so possibly it could be related to a .net framework versioning issue?  The target framework is 4.7.1 and that is loaded up on the machine PC.  Regedit shows Version 4.8.03761 and 528049 on the release element of the v4 Full hive.  This matches my own PC setup.

This is pretty much boilerplate caliburn.micro shellbootstrapper code with a log4net config activation thrown in.  I have used this code dozens of times with nary a problem!

Any advice on where to look for the problem would be most welcome!

Cam

```
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = new CompositionContainer(new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()));
        var batch = new CompositionBatch();

        batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
        batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
        batch.AddExportedValue(container);

        container.Compose(batch);
        dynamic aPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        dynamic ConfigurationFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(aPath, "log4net.config.xml");

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(ConfigurationFilePath))
        {
            dynamic ConfigurationFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(ConfigurationFilePath);
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(ConfigurationFile);
        }
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            log.Info("sType:" + serviceType + " key:" + key);
            string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
            log.Info("contract:" + contract);
            var exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

            if (exports.Any())
                return exports.First();

            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
        }
        catch (CompositionException cx)
        {
            log.Error("Composition Error in ShellBootStrapper: " + cx.Errors.Count + " msg: "+ cx.Message + "\nIE: " + cx.InnerException);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The exception text reads as follows:

Composition Error in ShellBootStrapper: 1 msg:The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) Illegal characters in path.

Resulting in: An exception occurred while trying to create an instance of type 'FDL.ShellViewModel'.

Resulting in: Cannot activate part 'FDL.ShellViewModel'.
Element: FDL.ShellViewModel -->  FDL.ShellViewModel -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="FDL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'FDL.ShellViewModel (ContractName="FDL.ShellViewModel")' from part 'FDL.ShellViewModel'.
Element: FDL.ShellViewModel (ContractName="FDL.ShellViewModel") -->  FDL.ShellViewModel -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="FDL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

So, now I am embarrassed.  My father-in-law went into the hospital and things got hectic.  After things calmed down, I (forgetting that I posted this question) put some logging into the bootstrapper to see what the illegal characters were.  What I found was that the bootstrapper was loading the ShellView and the ShellView was loading the correct UserControl and the UserControl had a setting in it that had the illegal characters!

I appreciate your willingness to help with this but it is all working now.  I found my mistake.
Thank you Frenchy and Jack for your comments!

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: coould you post your complete bootstrapper please? i dont see how you call FDL.ShellViewModel

Comment: Can you show `ShellViewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

This is from an older Bootstrapper I used awhile back. It should still work with CM, I know it works on .NetCore 3.0, 4.7.2 & 4.8.

**The Container**

```
private CompositionContainer Container;
```

**The Constructor:**

```
public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
        LogManager.GetLog = type => new DebugLog(type);
    }
```

**Configure:**

```
protected override void Configure()
    {
        var Catalog =
              new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>());

        Container = new CompositionContainer(Catalog);
        var Batch = new CompositionBatch();

        Batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
        Batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
        Batch.AddExportedValue(Container);
        Batch.AddExportedValue(Catalog);
        Container.Compose(Batch);
    }
```

**GetInstance:**

```
protected override object GetInstance(Type ServiceType, string key)
    {
        var Contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(ServiceType) : key;
        var Exports = Container.GetExportedValues<object>(Contract);

        if (Exports.Any()) return Exports.First();

        throw new Exception($"Could not locate any instances of contract: {Contract}.");
    }
```

**Build Up:**

```
protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        Container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
    }
```

**GetAllInstances:**

```
 protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type ServiceType)
    {
        return Container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(ServiceType));
    }
```

**Then Finally The Startup:**

```
protected override async void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {            
        await DisplayRootViewForAsync(typeof(IShell)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

**The Shell Should Look Something Like This**

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class ShellViewModel : Screen, IShell
{
    //Code...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Revan.  It is working and yes, this version of the ShellBootstrapper would work.  I have used this before.